# Popen does not wait for Sandboxie to finish

Tags: python, subprocess

i have an interesting problem with using Python's `subprocess.Popen` to run some executable ("`a.exe`") to generate an image file, `wait()` for it with `shell=False`, and then i will check the filesize of this image file using `os.path.getsize`.

when i use Popen to directly call `a.exe`, the file gets generated, and i can successfully retrieve the size of the image file.

however, as i am concerned about the security of this generation, now i use Popen with [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/), which in turns run `a.exe` within a sandbox. The problem i have is that when i try to use `getsize()`, the file is said to not exist. However, the image file is generated, perhaps just not at the point of time `getsize()` is called.

does Popen always `wait()` for the Sandboxie to complete? from the docs, it seems so but in practise it is not the case. How can i make sure my code waits for Sandboxie to complete before proceeding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.sandboxie.com/?StartCommandLine

You want `/wait`

> The parameter /wait can be used to run a program, wait for it to finish, and return the exit status from the program:
>
> ```
> "C:\Program Files\Sandboxie\Start.exe"  /wait cmd.exe
> ```